# How do I take a user input through HTML and feed it into my Python script as a variable?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Beginner here, I'm trying to code a website to take a URL as the input and then feed it into my script. Here is my Python script:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cgi
import subprocess, cgitb


app = Flask(__name__)

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
url = form.getvalue("market_url")

ua = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
data = requests.get(url, headers=ua)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')
```

And then my HTML looks like this:

```
  <section>
    <form action="./app.py" method="post"> 
      <p> Name: <input type="text" name="market_url" id="market_url" value=""
placeholder="Enter Market URL: " /></p> 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </section>
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong here? I keep getting an error that says "requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?"

Comment: Your field is not called "f_name".  It's called "market_url".

Comment: Sorry that was an older code. It's updated but still giving the same error

Comment: You have a very strange mixture of technologies here.  Is this actually a CGI script?  If so, then delete everything Flask-related.  You might print `form.keys()` and see if you're getting any values from the query.